# dcast in R - creating pivot table

Tags: r, casting, pivot-table

Here is my example

```
Student <- c('A',  'B', 'B')
Assessor <- c('C',  'D', 'D')
Score <- c(1, 5, 7)
df <- data.frame(Student, Assessor, Score)
df <- dcast(df, Student ~ Assessor,fun.aggregate=(function (x) x), value = 'Score')
print(df)
```

The output:

```
Using Score as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : unused argument (value = "Score")
```

While I want to get something like

```
    C    D
A   1    NaN
B   NaN  5
B   NaN  7
```

What I am missing?

In addition, if I replace `Score` with

```
Score <- c('foo', 'bar','bar')
```

The output will be:

```
Using Score as value column: use value.var to override.
Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : unused argument (value = "Score")
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Since `dcast` spread among unique values of the left side of the formula I think you can achieve your goal with a (not so elegant hack) but I bet there are other ways to do that with `table` maybe.

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(df, Student + Score ~ ...)[-2]
Using Score as value column: use value.var to override.
  Student  C  D
1       A  1 NA
2       B NA  5
3       B NA  7
```

The hack is to just spread by remaining `Student` and `Score` the same and then spread other variables (in this case `Assessor`) and the with `[-2]` remove the `Score` column in order to get the desired output (unless your first column is made by column names actually, which is impossible in base R; in that case you need a `data.table` solution)

Comment: Or else you can create a sequence column by group and then do the `dcast`

Answer (score 0):

Using the dev version of `tidyr` (0.3.0) [get it from github](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr).

First we complete the combinations of Student/Assessor, then we nest it all into a list, spread and then unnest the list into new rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% complete(Student, Assessor) %>%
       nest(Score) %>%
       spread(Assessor, Score) %>%
       unnest(C) %>%
       unnest(D)


  Student  C  D
1       A  1 NA
2       B NA  5
3       B NA  7
```